How to Retrieve ISAPI Endpoints for DS-K1T343 Hikvision Face ID Terminal and Fetch Today's Attendance Statistics?
I'm working with a Hikvision DS-K1T343 Face ID Terminal and need to integrate it with a software system. Specifically, I want to know how to access the ISAPI endpoints that are supported by this model. Additionally, I need to retrieve today's attendance statistics from the terminal using its API.
Could anyone provide guidance on:

The correct ISAPI endpoints for the DS-K1T343 model?
How to query the terminal for today's attendance data using those endpoints?

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!

which language do you want to program this in?

I am using python for that

Please register to tpp.hikvision.com, you will be provided with NDA form to sign  , and all the documentation will become available to you.
The documentation you download there will contain wattermark with your company name. If you share it and they find out, they can pursue legal actions.
Hence why you cannot see a lot of documentation in public. If any its on random forums.
Since your device is web based, you can always use Developer tools and see endpoints and all the CRUD that devices does.
